# Update pandas dataframe column with substring from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, validation, split

I have a dataframe where some of the informations are on the wrong field and I need to change it to the wright column. The problem is that those informations are user inserted, so they are in the middle of strings and in differents ways. The df below is a small example of the problem:

```
|         String          |      Info A      |      Info B      |
|-------------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        'some text'      |         50       |         60       |
|   'A=70, B=80, text'    |                  |                  |
|  'text, A = 10m, B:20'  |                  |                  |
```

The actual version of the df has 10 variables that I need to change and about 2mi rows.

What I need to do is put those informations on the right field, as shown on the first row of the example.

I tried some things but they all had a errors or would take to much time. If someone could help me think of a solution, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to get the variable names and values, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
variables = ['A', 'B']
regex = fr'\b({"|".join(variables)})\s*[=:]\s*(\d+)'
# '\\b(A|B)\\s*[=:]\\s*(\\d+)'

df.update(df['String']
 .str.extractall(regex)
 .reset_index(level=0)
 .pivot(index='level_0', columns=0, values=1)
 .add_prefix('Info ')
)
```

output:

```
                String Info A Info B
0            some text   50.0   60.0
1     A=70, B=80, text     70     80
2  text, A = 10m, B:20     10     20
```

Comment: This seems like a great approach but it didn't work so far. I changed the "pivot" to "pivot_table" because of an error, after the change the code compiles with no errors but the data are still on the original field. I'll try to make some changes to see if it works, thanks!

Comment: can you provide a reproducible form of your input? `df.to_dict('list')`

Comment: It is a huge dataframe, and it has informations I'm not able to share. I know it's harder to help in this scenario but if you have any clue of what might be happenning I can try it here. In a smaller scale the example shows what's happening. It took about 12 minutes to run your code with no errors or warnings but the output was exactly the same as the input df.

Comment: Well you can craft a reproducible dummy example as a DataFrame constructor. "*it didn't work so far*" is difficult to try to improve the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that can help you. For your example, you can do :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["String","Info A","Info B"])
df["String"]=['some text','A=70, B=80, text', 'text, A = 10m, B:20']
df["Info A"]=[50,None,None]
df["Info B"]=[60,None,None]

list_strings = list(df["String"])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["String","Info A","Info B"])

for str_ in list_strings:
    Nones = [None]*len(list(df.columns))
    dict_dummy = dict(zip(list(df.columns),Nones)) 

    split_str = str_.split(sep=",")
    
    for splited_elm in split_str :
        if "A" in splited_elm and ("=" in splited_elm or ":" in splited_elm):
            dict_dummy["Info A"] = splited_elm
            
        elif "B" in splited_elm and ("=" in splited_elm or ":" in splited_elm):
            dict_dummy["Info B"] = splited_elm
        
        else:
            dict_dummy["String"] = splited_elm
    
    new_df=new_df.append(dict_dummy,ignore_index=True)
```

Output :

```
new_df
Out[47]: 
      String    Info A Info B
0  some text      None   None
1       text      A=70   B=80
2       text   A = 10m   B:20
```

This little script help you to classify your elements. You can do another processing to make your df better.

Comment: I had some problems with for loops because of the size of the df, but I'll try this code to see if it does the work faster, thanks a lot!